# Grive synchronize only in one way (only upload)

Tags: grive

I'd like to have synchronizing of Google Drive with `grive` but only in one way, i.e. only upload.

Thanks to it I have:

- when a file is created in local drive, grive synchroinizes drives (upload),
- when the upload finishes I delete the file as I don't need it anymore (it's in the Google Drive now),
- grive does not download the file back to local drive with next grive synchronization trigger.

Is it possible?

Comment: GRIVE was a great tool but it sadly died on 20th April when Google discontinued service for the Google Documents List API version 3.0 API.  https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-google-drive-client-grive-and-grive-tools AND https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/  for more background...